# I cannot figure out how to center my nav bar in css

Tags: html, css, web, formatting, nav

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

[Here is my html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Mfa.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Elliott Lambert</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
      <div class="row">
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="">EXPERIENCE</a></li>
          <li><a href="">ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS</a></li>
          <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="">FAQs</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </header>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here is my css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwsrr.png)

```
.main-nav
{
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 600px;
}

.main-nav li
{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-nav li a
{
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

[Here is what my index.html looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgMWR.png)

@jvdmr Edited to add code from screenshots - I believe the third screenshot combined with the code and the title provides enough information for this question.

Comment: Instead of posting screenshots you should insert your code directly in here. Create a snippet for people to debug. Easier for everyone.

Comment: try using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: please put your code in your question, not in a screenshot, this makes it easier for people to copy and test if needed.

Secondly, it doesn't look like you've tried to center anything at all. Your navbar is `float`ing to the right, and has a `margin-right` of 600px meaning it'll stay 600px away from the right side of the window.

Try adding this:

```
.main-nav {
  margin: 30px auto auto;
  list-type: none;
  width: intrinsic;
}
```

instead of the current .main-nav entry in your style.css. Keep the rest of the style.css as-is.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to this website and coding. I'll make sure to copy and paste my code next time, your answer also helped.

Answer (score 0):

Some things here:

1. don't forget to close your div and ul tags!
2. add this in for .row:

   .row {
       display: -webkit-flex;
       display: flex;
       -webkit-flex-direction: row;
       flex-direction: row;
       -webkit-justify-content: center;
       justify-content: center;
       align-content: stretch;
   }

This allows your .row to act as a container across your page with the children being centered in the container.

3. replace your .main-nav{} with the following:

   .main-nav {
     list-style:none;
     margin-top: 30px;
   }

by removing the float and the margin-left you allow the display:flex to do its job.